# Air Conditioning button "on" by default

Tags: ac, nissan, versa

re: 2015 Nissan Versa Note

When I turn my air on, the AC button is lit up and on by default no matter how I left it on last use.  If it have the temperature turned to max heat, will having the AC button on have a negative consequence to how heat is dispersed?

I was thinking to get a remote starter for the winter, but it'd defeat the purpose if I have to go out there first and push the AC button every time.

Comment: Is this with the defroster on, or is it just any which way you leave it (floor, bi-level, defrost, etc) the A/C will be running upon startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No negative consequence.  Some manufacturers do this because the A/C unit also acts as a dehumidifier so running the A/C helps dry out the air in humid climates.  In some areas, at some times of year, you run the A/C while running the air with a temperature set somewhere in the middle, instead of full-cold.  This is to prevent window-fogging.  This is common in the South of the USA in the Spring/Fall.

The heat exchanger has no impact on the A/C condenser.  The heat exchanger or heater core is basically a small radiator inside the dash that heats the air using engine heat.  This heat is dispersed via the fans in the dash.